# host a database website with entity framework in the production server

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I developed an asp.net website (using webforms) and for database connection I used Entity Framework. On my local computer everything is working fine. Now I try to host it I am having a problem. I have copied my files to the production server and attached my SQL Server database and set my connection string to:

```
 <add name="ConnectionString" 
      connectionString="Data Source=SQL5003.Smarterasp.net;Initial Catalog=DB_9C4561_WFormBlog;User Id=DB_9C4561_WFormBlog_admin;Password=mydbpwd"
      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

but when I test my website am getting error:

> Keyword not supported: 'data source'

When I removed "data source", it started complaining of "Initial catalog" keyword not supported.

Please help me out. You can refer me step by step tutorial or material that can put me through. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below format, I have my database on smarterasp.net and it works well

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Persist Security Info=False;database=DB_9C4561_WFormBlog;server=SQL5003.Smarterasp.net;user id=DB_9C4561_WFormBlog_admin;password=mydbpwd;Current Language=English;Connection Timeout=60;" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Mehrdad for your intervention. I tried the above, but it was giving me error:  No connection string named 'BlogModel' could be found in the application config file.

Comment: I have corrected the name issue. But I am now getting error:  Keyword not supported: 'persist security info'.